# why can't I read input from user

Tags: c, struct

This was the question

Write a C program to consider 3 bank accounts A, B and C (Consider name of the person, account number and balance). Get all the required details from the user. Transfer 2000 rs from account B to C and 1000 rs from A to B. Make sure the changes are reflected in all the bank objects properly. Finally, display the name of customer who had highest bank balance.

And this is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

struct det
{
    char name;
    int acc;
    float bal;
};

struct det de[3];

void add(char from,char to,float *amo)
{
    int j;
    for(j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
        if(de[j].name==from)
        {
            de[j].bal=de[j].bal-*amo;
        }
        if(de[j].name==to)
        {
            de[j].bal=de[j].bal+*amo;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i,k;
    de[0].name='A';
    de[1].name='B';
    de[2].name='C';
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d %f",&de[i].acc,&de[i].bal);
    }
    char from,to;
    float val;
    int tot,m;
    printf("How many times you want to transfer\n");
    scanf("%d",&tot);
    for(m=0;m<tot;m++)
    {
        printf("From\n");
        //gets(from);
        scanf("%c",&from);
        printf("To\n");
        scanf("%c",&to);
        //gets(to);
        printf("Amount\n");
        scanf("%f",&val);
        add(from,to,&val);
    }
    for(k=0;k<3;k++)
    {
        printf("%c %.2f",de[k].name,de[k].bal);
    }
}
```

Every part of my code works perfectly but it does not take input and store it in from variable. What's wrong in my code?

Comment: The last input for `scanf("%d %f",&de[i].acc,&de[i].bal)` ended with the `Enter` key, right? That `Enter` key will be added as a newline into the input buffer, to be read by the next call to `scanf("%c",&from)`. Add a leading space in that format to skip all leading white-space (like newlines), as in `scanf(" %c",&from)`

Comment: Using `scanf` for line-based input is messy. You may want to use [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) and [`strtod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof) instead. See this link for further information: [A beginners' guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)